# Get XML tag in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd

I have the following XML schema (actually it is an XSD of a webservice):

```
<xs:element name='serviceMethod'>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence><xs:element name='valueIWantToKnow'/></xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In Java, I do know the 'serviceMethod', but I want to know the value of the name attribute of the element nested in the servicemethod element.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Use a library such as Apache XmlSchema to traverse your schema.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains all the XML parsing using dom parser, please have a look, it should solve your problem.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) ([java example](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/java-xpath.shtml))

```
//serviceMethod/valueIWantToKnow
```